# Two ways e-mail address obfuscation service

Tags: email

Currently if I want to register on a service with an unique email address, I can use a + with any string after the username on gmail like  `peter_parker+specialtest123@gmail.com` where `specialtest123` would be ignored and sent to `peter_parket@gmail.com` , but it has two major problems,  it exposes my email address anyway and some services actively fight against it.

What I would like to know if exists or is possible is a service that allows me to easily create emails aliases with specific usernames, that would hide my email address while allowing me to send and receive from this alias, something like:

- spiderman@easyaliasservice.com -> peterparker@gmail.com
- emails_from_aliexpress@easyaliasservice.com -> peterparker@gmail.com
- emails_from_paypal@easyaliasservice.com -> peterparker@gmail.com
- peter_crypto@easyaliasservice.com -> peterparker@gmail.com

this would achieve both the privacy I would like and the have the added benefit of just letting me remove an alias and get rid of some of the more pesky spammers out there (like aliexpress who tends to get back at my inbox no matter what I do)

Comment: Have you tried searching for such a provider yourself? Whaat did you find, and how were they inadequate? I got some useful results with a search for ***privacy email services with aliases***; some were free, some were paid, and some were freemium.

Answer (score 1):

Found anonaddy.com is exactly what I want to do